# Той, що розміщений на підлозі

Tags: значення-слів

Чи правильно використовувати слово "підлоговий" для опису приладу, що розміщується на підлозі?

[image: Прилад з написом на етикетці: «ТСЧ-2. Щит інформаційний підлоговий двосторонній»]

Comment: @Sasha, оригінальне зображення "правильне", це його сервіс хостінгу розвертає. Я витатрив біля години і так і не зміг його поставити у правильному вигляді. Буду дуже вдячний за допомогу!

Comment: @Sasha, дуже дякую! До речі, щит зображений на фото розташований в середині ст. м. Контрактова площа, м. Київ.

Comment: Правда, зобрага має помилку: _підлог**и**вий_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

І справді, СУМ має слово *підлоговий*, однак я засумнівався в його значенні. Тому вирішив пошукати ще в різних словниках (а саме в російсько-українських словниках я почав шукати переклад слова *напольный*), і ось які варіанти там [пропонують](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

**Наземний**

- Російсько-український словник з інженерних технологій 2013р. (Марія Ганіткевич, Богдан Кінаш)
- Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р. (І. Шелудько, Т. Садовський)
- Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009 — джерело не можна вважати найдійним

**Підлоговий**

- Словник [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9): бачимо приклад *підлоговий годинник*.
- Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009

  Слово *підлоговий* є в різних словниках, а тому його можна вживати.

**Долівковий** — очевидно утворене від [долівка](http://sum.in.ua/s/dolivka)

- Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009

Answer (score 7):

В [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidloghovyj)  та [ВТССУМ](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/943405.html) присутнє слово "підлоговий"

> ПІДЛО́ГОВИЙ, а, е. Прикм. до підлога. *Для безшумних підлогових
>   покриттів у лікарнях, установах і житлових приміщеннях застосовують
>   «рубопластик» (Наука і життя, 8, 1958, 54).*

Отже, так використання слова "підлоговий"  для опису приладу, що розміщується на підлозі є правильним.

Наприклад, [підлогові ваги](https://www.google.com/search?ei=ugVQXMSBL4eHrwSBraXICw&q=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%20&oq=%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30l5.54497.60295..60619...11.0..2.103.1196.14j1......0....1..gws-wiz.....6..0i71j35i39j0i67j0j0i131i67j0i131j0i203.UKa8PnYgCDM)